# How can I join 2 rows in a dataframe into 1 row in a new one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merging-data

I am filtering an external data source that is formatted as an excel file. There is nothing I can do to change how the file is generated. I need to filter out rows that are useless and combine pairs of rows into one. The process I have so far works on the filtering, but not on the joining of related data in two successive rows into one row.

The dataframes are not converted nicely for stackoverflow, but I have hand-tweaked them below.

## Data Transformations

#### Convert downloads into useful formats

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas          import DataFrame
from pandas.io.excel import read_excel
cpath = os.path.join (download_path, classes_report)
print (pd.__version__)

df = pd.read_excel (cpath, sheetname=0, header=None)
df.to_string()

0.14.1
```

`0                               1         2      3     4         5
0     Session: 2014-2015                             NaN       NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
1      Class Information                             Age  Enrolled    Key  Room       NaN
2                   Math                              10   12 / 18  03396   110  09:00:00
3              Teacher:                    Joe M Teacher       NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
4                    NaN                             NaN       NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
5                                                              NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
6                                                              NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
7                    NaN                             NaN       NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
8                    NaN                             NaN       NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
9   Number of Classes: 1  Number of Students: 12 / 18          NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
10     Class Information                            Ages  Enrolled    Key  Room       NaN
11                   Art                         18 - 80    3 / 24  03330   110  10:00:00
12             Teacher:                John A Instructor       NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
13                   NaN                             NaN       NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
14                                                             NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
15                                                             NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN`

```
# Eliminate any rows where first column is NaN, contains 'Number of Classes', 'Class Information'
# or is blank
# The 5th column is tuition.

cf = df[df[0].notnull ()][1:]
cf = cf [~cf[0].str.contains ('Number of Classes')]
bf = cf[~cf[0].isin ([' ', 'Class Information'])]
bf.to_string()
```

`0                  1        2      3    4         5
2        Math                 10  12 / 18  03396  110  09:00:00
3   Teacher:       Joe M Teacher      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN
11        Art            18 - 80   3 / 24  03330  110  10:00:00
12  Teacher:   John A Instructor      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN`

```
left  = DataFrame(bf.values [::2], index=bf.index[::2])
right = DataFrame(bf.values [1::2], index=bf.index[1::2])
pd.concat([left, right], axis=1).to_string ()
```

`0        1        2      3    4         5          0                  1    2    3    4    5
2   Math       10  12 / 18  03396  110  09:00:00        NaN                NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN  Teacher:       Joe M Teacher  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11   Art  18 - 80   3 / 24  03330  110  10:00:00        NaN                NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
12   NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN  Teacher:   John A Instructor  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN`

The goal here was to have the last five columns of the "Math" row to contain the columns starting with "Teacher:", and similarly for the "Art" row, leaving a dataframe with two rows instead of four.

Comment: Try `pd.concat([left, right], axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: You explicitly set the index for your right df, if it's the same number of rows and you want them to align why not just use the same indices as left: `right = DataFrame(bf.values [1::2], index=left.index)`? then the concat would produce what you want no?

Comment: @EdChum - That works. If you write it as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to `concat` aligned the 2 df's by index thereby producing a disjointed df with 4 rows rather than 2 rows:

```
right = DataFrame(bf.values [1::2], index=bf.index[1::2])
```

The above creates a new df using the values from your df but you also took the index values also, seeing as the left and right df's have the same number of rows and you're want to concatenate them column-wise so that the indices align then you can just use the same index from the left df:

```
right = DataFrame(bf.values [1::2], index=left.index)
```

This will produce the desired concatenated df.